# PIXI.Application is not a constructor [PIXIJS]

Tags: javascript, pixi.js

i start a little project using pixijs. I follow that tutorial : https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=FrnXCZmmAZo but it doesn't work for me.

HTML :

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <title></title>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
</head>
    <script src="./node_modules.js/pixi.js/dist/pixi.min.js"></script>
<body>
    <script src="index.js" type="module"></script>
</body>
```

I got pixi module with the following command : npm install pixi.js

index.js :

```
import * as PIXI from './node_modules/pixi.js/dist/pixi.min.js';

const log = console.log;
const app = new PIXI.Application();
```

Error :

```
PIXI.Application is not a constructor[En savoir plus] index.js:4:13
<anonyme>
http://localhost:3000/index.js:4:13
InnerModuleEvaluation self-hosted:4290:5 evaluation self-hosted:4243:9
```

**UPDATE**

HTML :

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <title></title>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
</head>
<body>
    <script src="./node_modules.js/pixi.js/dist/pixi.min.js"></script>
    <script src="index.js" type="module"></script>
</body>
</html>
```

index.js :

```
const log = console.log;
const app = new PIXI.Application();
```

Error :

```
PIXI is not defined
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The tutorial doesn't use modules.

`PIXI` is exposed globally: https://github.com/pixijs/pixi.js/blob/v4.8.1/src/index.js#L51

If you remove the import, and fix the typo in the script tag, it should work.

HTML:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <title></title>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
</head>
<body>
    <script src="./node_modules/pixi.js/dist/pixi.min.js"></script>
    <script src="index.js" type="module"></script>
</body>
</html>
```

index.js:

```
const log = console.log;
const app = new PIXI.Application();
```

Comment: Thank you for helping but another error occured. I update my post. Furthermore, i saw the git repo : https://github.com/pixijs/pixi.js/blob/v4.8.1/src/index.js#L51 and i had not clone repo. Should I clone it?

Comment: @wyllisMonteiro Please note that you have to remove the extension from the `node_modules.js` directory, it's simply `node_modules`.

Answer (score 1):

If you're using npm, I got this error cause I ran `npm install pixi` (incorrect) instead of `npm install pixi.js` (correct).